# Scanning SCSI_HOST: Environment: VMWARE Workstation, VM OS RHEL 7.0

Tags: rhel, vmware, scsi

After the adding the new HDD through settings in VMWARE workstation, the sdx are discovered through scanning the SCSI_Host. My question is that, in the following command how I can include globbing. Sometimes it happens that under the /sys/class/scsi_host/ folder there are almost 32 hosts. I need to scan through host0 to host31 sometimes.

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan
```

Any suggestions how I can use globbing here to scan the scsi_host in  a single go.
Environment: VMWARE Workstation 10
             OS: RHEL 7

Answer (score 1):

You can just repeat the echo for each file with a simple shell command, for example:

```
for file in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan
do  echo "- - -" >$file
done
```